# how to connect or uninstall ubuntu touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, touchscreen, adb

I installed ubuntu touch in my **Xperia Z1** following the wiki https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices/minato 
everything was gone fine but after I started the phone the **touchscreen** doen't work and stay in the state of choosing the language 
I want to **recover** my android system or how can I fix the **touchscreen** ?

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached 

$lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8086:0a66 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0fce:019e Sony Ericsson Mobile Communications AB 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

using the Flashtool

```
INFO - Device connected with USB debugging off
INFO - for 2011 devices line, be sure you are not in MTP mode
```

Comment: It is not wourth fixing ubuntu touch, it is no longer developed. To reflash android, use the  tools provided by sony: https://developer.sonymobile.com/open-devices/flash-tool/how-to-download-and-install-the-flash-tool/

Comment: flashtool said: INFO - Device connected with USB debugging off
INFO - for 2011 devices line, be sure you are not in MTP mode
how can I deal with this ?